# How does Donald Knuth tests new version of tex?

Tags: tex-core, knuth

Donald Knuth mentions in the TeX: the program that he has used the pascal programming language described in the user manual of pascal by jensen and wirth in 1975 to implement TeX. My question is when knuth released the current version of tex in 2014, how did he test it? what tools did he use to compile tex himself? how does he compile tex himself for testing the new version? does he use web2c? I am curious to know how he himself compiles tex from source?

Comment: TeX is frozen. Bug fixes only. As bugs get fixed, the version number tends to `\pi`. But there are no new versions of TeX in the sense you mean.

Comment: @cfr The program must be compiled to test the bug fixes anyhow.

Comment: I'm not sure this is answerable by anyone other than DEK: that probably makes it OT!

Comment: There is an official test for the TeX engine.  If your program passes the test, you can call it TeX.  The rest is all written in TeX itself.

Comment: I'm not Donald Knuth. I'm a user who happens to be drinking wine at happy hour. But if I were Donald Knuth, I'd still be drinking wine at happy hour, instead of worrying about this. If you are reading this, DK, cheers!

Comment: @egreg Maybe DK is like Beethoven: doesn't need to test it outside the mind. Admittedly, you still have to compile the programme to make *use* of the fixes, but, strictly speaking, you don't have to test them.

Comment: I thought that someone here knows something but apparently you all are as clueless as I am. I can not really stop laughing at some of the silly comments above. I wil ask Knuth directly then. I just hoped that perhaps Barbara Beeton may know about it.

Comment: Knuth uses web2c these days (TeX Live on Debian, according to one of his log files), at least for “production runs”. He tried to use GPC (GNU Pascal) when he got a new computer in 2000, but ran into incompatibilities in the compiler. ([Thread](http://www.g-n-u.de/pipermail/gpc/2000-April/003758.html)) I don't know if they got resolved. The [ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/tex/local/](http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/tex/local/) directory, which has/had Knuth's “local” changefiles (etc.) for building TeX on his system, was last updated in 2009. `…/tex/` in 2002. HTH, let me know what you find out.

Comment: Friends, does DK read the exchanges here? Is he aware of this exchange forum? (I am a big fan of DK, and I still use many TeX commands in LaTeX - Thanks a lot!!)